# Bootstrap three columns unexpected behavior on desktop devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make proper order of three bootstrap's columns but I can achive it only for small devices. On desktop devices it only works fine if "important" div has hight greater than "profile" div but I have situation when "important" div has hight less than "profile". In that situation my "other" tab positions below "important" div, but not below "profile" div as it should.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

```css
.profile {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.important {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.other {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 profile">
      PROFILE DATA<br>
      1<br>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 important pull-right">
      IMPORTANT DATA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 other col-md-4">
      OTHER DATA
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 profile">
      PROFILE DATA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 important pull-right">
      IMPORTANT DATA<br>
      1<br>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 other col-md-4">
      OTHER DATA
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend of mine helped me to solve this problem. Thanks Rados Pavlicevic!

I only need to add

```
style="clear: left;"
```

on my OTHER DATA div.

Here is a working code sample:

```css
.profile {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.important {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.other {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 profile">
      PROFILE DATA<br>
      1<br>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 important pull-right">
      IMPORTANT DATA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 other col-md-4" style="clear:left">
      OTHER DATA
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 profile">
      PROFILE DATA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 important pull-right">
      IMPORTANT DATA<br>
      1<br>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 other col-md-4" style="clear:left">
      OTHER DATA
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap per row hold 12 column maximum. And you give each row 16 column[Read Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

```css
.profile {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.important {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.other {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 profile">
      PROFILE DATA<br>
      1<br>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 important pull-right">
      IMPORTANT DATA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 other col-md-4">
      OTHER DATA
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 profile">
      PROFILE DATA
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 important pull-right">
      IMPORTANT DATA<br>
      1<br>
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 other col-md-4">
      OTHER DATA
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that, thanks. If there is no space for another column, it will be placed in a next row. You change my col-md-8 to col-md-4. It not what I want to achieve. Please look at my answer below, I've found solution. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: look mate .. in your question 1st line. "trying to make proper order of three bootstrap's columns " after that in your code row contain 16 column. So that's the reason I have answer this. And cngrtzz you find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 blue">
        PROFILE DATA
        <br> 1
        <br> 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 red">
        IMPORTANT DATA
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 green">
        OTHER DATA
    </div>
</div>
```

---

http://codepen.io/Psyll1/pen/XjBQNp

Comment: Try to add some more data to IMPORTANT DATA div and you'll see a problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEkBkE Look at my anwer below, my friend helped me to solve this problem.